# Will sending keywords info to AdMob get better ads

Tags: android, admob, ads, keyword, target

We can provide keywords to admob so the ads can be targeted. Will it get better ads or ads related with keywords?
  We can do this by using the addKeyword function when creating a request. Like this:

```
AdRequest.Builder builder = new AdRequest.Builder()
    .addTestDevice("and id for your device")
    .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
    .addKeyword("orange")
    .addKeyword("yellow")
    .addKeyword("blue");
```

This method is documented here: http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdRequest.Builder.html

Comment: Yes, the docs say "for targeting purposes". That probably means it will use the keywords you provided to find appropriate ads. But whether that is "better" depends on your definition of "better".

Comment: Better says that it returns ads related with keywords.